# Difference between Power law distribution and Exponential distribution?

Tags: distributions, power-law, exponential-distribution

[image]

What is the difference between Power law distribution and Exponential distribution?

They both look similar!

Comment: this is not programming related, and the difference is perfectly explained by the names (?)

Comment: The CDFs are different, so despite the passing similarity of the pdf plots, they are distinct  distributions.

Comment: The Wikipedia entries on distributions are nice because they routinely provide a list of properties, always on the right hand side below plots of typical graphs.  *Please read them.* That will give a clear account of differences and similarities.